# On untimely speculation

Tags: ethics

These are some doubts and thoughts I have about which I am looking for commentaries, especially from Greeks or Romans. You can also tell me what you think yourself.

It seems I developed a habit (why?) of speculating on everything to which I direct my mind or my actions. This happens many times in small talk, and I allow it because there it is many times harmless, and many times expected. It is not unusual to find myself trying to lay out universal rules about mundane stuff.

Now, sometimes questions appear about a particular thing-—like they like to come to mind when attempting to know something: what is this? what is the form of the thing? what kinds are there? and similar questions. And it happens that the thing is mundane, concrete, like love, for example, and I begin reflecting on the mundane thing from experience, and I end rambling from imagination. It is not difficult to distinguish experience from imagination, and to know which originates the thought, because when something is told by experience, there is no room for doubt.

By this effect I am fortunately removed from speculation many times, when I am asking questions and having in mind only possibilities and obscurity, and then strikes experience and all is made clear. I hate this habit.

I am pretty sure (anonymous here) these many doubts and surreptitious, useless speculation will clear up after more reading of the ancients, experience and education.

Comment: Can you give a specific example? Your description is vague.

Comment: This post does not appear to have a clear question.   Please retry with a clearly articulated question.